# how to execute the test cases of PVplayer in android?

Tags: android, testing, sdp, opencore

hi can you tell me how to execute the test cases defined in /external/opencore/engines/player/test/src in the donut code?

I have seen the PVplayer documentation , but that does not provide any information.
I am trying to run an SDP file in the PVplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the following steps to run the PV Player engine tests (I have done all this with donut code and product Sapphire):

1.You have to include the following line in `/external/opencore/Android.mk` while making build:

```
#include $(PV_TOP)/engines/player/test/Android.mk
```

Either uncomment this (if its commented) or remove any check which is avoiding this line to be included.

2.Build and install the images into phone.

3.Now open shell (use `adb shell` command). go to directory `/system/bin`.
There will be an excutable `pvplayer_engine_test`. Now run the following command:

`pvplayer_engine_test -test x y -source xyz.mp4 -logfile -logall`

where x is the start test case number and y is the end test
case number.

(For more command line options, please refer `pvplayer_engine_unit_test_guide.pdf` which is available at `/external/opencore/doc` location).

Hope this helps.